# Robust way to find a connection limit on any machine

Tags: java, connection, port, netty, limits

I need to find out an approximate limit of connections to remote host from current machine, and ideally it should work at any OS with java.
You reach a connection limit when connecting to remote hosts massively and get BindException or ConnectException or SocketException depending on a OS in this case.

I don't think there is an exact way to get this limit as it depends on current network activity and OS settings (ulimit e.g.), so I'm trying to find a robust empirical way.

Currently I'm opening connections at highest possible rate (every 1 microseconds, if less - I got an VM InternalError) until I get exceptions and then calculate rate as: `number of connections so far / duration`, I use Netty for this, here is the code, main loop:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stop) {
        try {
            ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(addr);
            connected.incrementAndGet();
        } catch (ChannelException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof SocketException) {
                stop = handleLimitErrors(e.getCause());
            }
        }

        TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(1);
    }
```

netty channel handler:

```
private class ErrorHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        e.getChannel().close();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) throws Exception {
        Throwable exc = e.getCause();
        e.getChannel().close();

        if (exc instanceof BindException || exc instanceof ConnectException) {
            stop = handleLimitErrors(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

and counter:

```
private boolean handleLimitErrors(Throwable e) {
    return  (errors.incrementAndGet() > 10);
}
```

[>>> Full code here](https://github.com/yetanothercoder/main/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/yetanothercoder/tests/stress/ConnectionLimitFinder.java)

Is there a better/robust way?
I'm going to use it on any major OS (Linux/MacOS/Win) at least.

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As I know you are right - there isn't the exact way. It depends on (another) machine settings and it's what you haven't under control. The way you provided is one from more ways on how to test connection limit for another machine. Happy hacking :-)

Comment: it's not hacking ) it's for stress test application that you can run on any available machine

Comment: @yetanothercoder what about using [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for stress-testing?

Comment: we need more custom logic for each request +it's slow as it's based on old thread-per-socket model